# Is web.AllowUnsafeUpdates default value always false in Sharepoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, object-model, sharepoint-object-model

This is my sample code:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web
SPList list = web.Lists["TestList"];

try {
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    list.Title = "Test";
    list.Update();
}

finally {
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
}
```

I removed finally code block, then tried it again. I found "web.AllowUnsafeUpdates" is still false.
Does it mean setting `web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false` is not necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`web.AllowUnsafeUpdates` is set for duration of request (for SPContext.Current.Web) or for lifetime of corresponding SPWeb object if one is obtained from SPSite via `GetWeb(...)` or `Webs[]`.

Depending on what "tried again" means you could be getting fresh copy of SPWeb for new request.

It is good practice to keep `AllowUnsafeUpdates` to be tru for very scoped pieces of code as you do with try/finally. There could be other code that would run during the same request and by mistake be able to update objects when it should not be allowed.